# Report and Invoice UWP Application

Tags: xaml, uwp, reporting

I design a UWP application.
In this one I am asked to make many reports that they are invoices or print delivery for example.
These can therefore have different models and these can be fixed or dynamic. 
I explore different ideas:
   - In the old application in WPF, we used an old version of DevExpress but it's really not easy to make reports simply and scalable ways easily
   - There are indeed things like Telerik, ComponentOne but it's really expensive for what it does and I can not find an open source component.
   - I looked to be able to make the models in XAML and be able to print them which would be ideal, however it works well with text but with tables (listbox, listview, datagrid ...) I can not manage the pagination.

Do you have any ideas? I do not know Power Bi Embedded well but maybe be an idea? I would like something scalable and simple to implement and without having to pay exhobirating sums for this kind of component.

Answer (score 1):

use all in one **DataGrid** for enterprise LOB apps on uwp platform, it offers you editing, filtering and sorting etc as well : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid

use **Print helper** to print stuff from your uwp app. : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/printhelper

> Also please do look through other controls and helpers within **windows community toolkit** you might find some other stuff as well to help and simplify your uwp app developing experience :)